# Count Number of Consecutive Occurrence of values in Table with new partition count although repeated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number, partition-by

```
create table #t_Jenas (Id int, Name char)

insert into #t_Jenas values
(1, 'A'),
(2, 'A'),
(3, 'B'),
(4, 'B'),
(5, 'B'),
(6, 'B'),
(7, 'C'),
(8, 'B'),
(9, 'B')
```

for row number partition by, if repeated rows, the number will continue that makes the minus column is not ascending. any idea how to make the partition number starts from 1 although repeat rows as data above?

```
select name,row_number() over (order by id) as cont ,row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as newcount,( row_number() over (order by id)-row_number() over (partition by name order by id)) as rowminusnewcount  --, count(*) as cnt
from #t_Jenas
```

Actual:

```
name    cont    newcount    rowminusnewcount
A   1   1   0
A   2   2   0
B   3   1   2
B   4   2   2
B   5   3   2
B   6   4   2
C   7   1   6
B   8   5   3
B   9   6   3
```

Expected:

```
name    cont    newcount    rowminusnewcount
A   1   1   0
A   2   2   0
B   3   1   2
B   4   2   2
B   5   3   2
B   6   4   2
C   7   1   6
B   8   1   7
B   9   2   7
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic for the last column.

Comment: . . I rolled back your last edit.  Users of Stack Overflow much prefer text tables to images.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the meaning of the last column:

```
select name, id,
       row_number() over (partition by grp, name order by id) as new_count,
       count(*) over (order by min_grp_id) - count(*) over (partition by grp, name)
from (select t.*, min(id) over (partition by grp, name) as min_grp_id
      from (select t.*,
                   (row_number() over (order by id) - row_number() over (partition by name order by id)
                   ) as grp
            from t_Jenas t
           ) t
     ) t
order by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7b7179defc62ac12dcd7a6d092213806) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is `cont`, `newcount` and `rowminusnewcount` all are row_numbers. I modified `id` to show the idea.

```
create table #t_Jenas (Id int, Name char);

insert into #t_Jenas values
(10, 'A'),
(20, 'A'),
(30, 'B'),
(40, 'B'),
(50, 'B'),
(60, 'B'),
(70, 'C'),
(80, 'B'),
(90, 'B');

select name,  cont,
       row_number() over (partition by grp, name order by id) as new_count,
       cont - row_number() over (partition by grp, name order by id) rowminusnewcount 
from (
 select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as cont
      , row_number() over (order by id) - row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as grp
       from #t_Jenas t
     ) t
order by id
```

Result

```
name    cont    new_count   rowminusnewcount
A   1   1   0
A   2   2   0
B   3   1   2
B   4   2   2
B   5   3   2
B   6   4   2
C   7   1   6
B   8   1   7
B   9   2   7
```